# Enable Careers and Jobs in app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Please provide the Careers and Jobs features in the app. This will help us to closely interact with employers. It will be an additional advantage if you provide chat option with employers too.

We, as job seeker, would like to see ratings and feedback of previous employees too for that company, before making a decision of job change.