# Can't load private message

Tags: bug, android-app

Someone sent me a message, when I try to open it in the app, it says it can't, but will load it in the browser instead. But at this point my browser knows to open SO links in the app, so it goes back to the app. Fortunately it ends there and doesn't fall into an infinite loop.

In the end I'm unable to read my messages without resetting app settings.

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: MotoG3

  - OS Version: 6.0 (36)

---

Not exact duplicate: I didn't know what kind of notification this is, there is no indication. I don't really care if the job notifications are opened in the app natively or with webview. Also: there is a (finite) redirection loop between Chrome and The App.

Comment: You mean a moderator message? I guess it is by design you can't open them in the app. The infinite loop though is something to be fixed.

Comment: It's a "jobs message". BTW It's not marked as such in the app.

Comment: Those should indeed link to your browser since the app doesn't support those notifications.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284992/careers-from-the-mobile-feed-lead-to-pointless-home-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Careers and Jobs in app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281267/enable-careers-and-jobs-in-app)

Comment: Not exact duplicate: I didn't know what kind of notification this is, there is no indication. Also: the loop.